# Is it OK to keep reference to a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I have FragmentActivity with Navigation mode (of ActionBar) set as `ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS`.

The tabs allow users to switch between two fragments, a listFragment and a mapFragment.The mapFragment contains a google Map. The code controls switching between the two fragments.

```
@Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    // When the given tab is selected, show the tab contents in the
    // container view.

    if(tab==tab_buyer_browse){
        if(mListFragment==null){
            mListFragment = new ItemListFragment(this,new ItemArrayAdapter(this));
        }
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ItemListFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER,
            tab.getPosition() + 1);
        mListFragment.setArguments(args);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, mListFragment).commit();
    }
    else if (tab==tab_buyer_location){
        if(mapFragment==null){
        //every time,on destroy called anyway, and exception raise. it looks like there is no point maintain a reference to mapFragment ?
            mapFragment = new ItemMapFragment(this);
        }
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.container, mapFragment).commit();
    }
```

I maintains the references to the two fragments. I think in this way I can avoid creating new fragments and reuse old one every time user switch tabs. there is no problem with ListFragment, but if I switch to mapFragment TWICE, exception raises saying the fragment has been destroyed.

I end up creating new mapFragment every time user switch tab and I can experience that UI is sluggish when I switch.

So my question is, is it a good practice to maintain reference of fragments in parent FragmentActivity?

If not, is there any way for me to control lifecycle of fragment, or at least reuse them as much as possible to avoid sluggish UI?

Comment: It should be fine. You're not "leaking" anything (strictly speaking) since if the parent is destroyed, your children are also marked as garbage. If you don't mind the extra memory usage and you can clearly see that it's adding performance benefits to your app, you should go for it. Remember that even Google does it (case in point, ViewPager that caches the next and previous pages) and they do it by creating it in advance and keeping a reference to it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [FragmentPageAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentPagerAdapter) and a ViewPager to have a tabbed fragments as well as support for swiping left/right. It will handle the fragments for you.